# Check if logged into Facebook Application (Mobile), via Mobile Web

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile-website

My question is as follows;

I am trying to check if a user has logged into facebook via the facebook application on their handset (Android / iOS) from a mobile website.

Is this possible, have you done this before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It is impossible to check other domain cookies / application data.